# CKEditor custom config not working, And it has different options inside and outside of admin panel

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

based on [customizing CKEditor editor](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#optional-customizing-ckeditor-editor) I declared a custom config in `settings.py`:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
        'toolbar_CustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Bold', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'paragraph', 'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 
                '-',  'spellchecker' ]},
        ],
    },
}
```

this config is used in `models.py`:

```
description = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor', blank=True)
```

in html file I use ckeditor  in this way:

```
<form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <textarea   name="message" 
                    id="message" 
                    class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.15.0/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'message');
    CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
    CKEDITOR.config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
</script>
```

this config is not working. how to load it?

before declaring this config, I was getting different editor options inside admin panel and outside ot it:

inside admin panel:

[image]

and outside it:

[image]

how to fix this config so all pages have same config?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

there should be a script tag below the html file like it:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'message' );
    CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
    CKEDITOR.config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
        { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
        { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
        { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
        { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
    ];
    CKEDITOR.config.removeButtons = 'Source,Save,NewPage,ExportPdf,Preview,Print,Templates,Cut,Copy,Paste,PasteText,PasteFromWord,Find,Replace,SelectAll,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,CopyFormatting,RemoveFormat,Italic,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Blockquote,CreateDiv,Outdent,Indent,JustifyLeft,JustifyCenter,JustifyRight,JustifyBlock,Language,Link,Image,Flash,Unlink,Anchor,Table,HorizontalRule,Smiley,SpecialChar,PageBreak,Iframe,FontSize,Font,Format,Styles,TextColor,ShowBlocks,Maximize,About,BGColor';
</script>
```

the `message` is the name of textfield in the HTML file.

using config in `settings.py` and editing `ckeditor.js` in CKEditor directory didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': 
            [{'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Bold', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'paragraph', 'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', '-',  'spellchecker']}],
    }
}
```

**Ckeditor will look for default setting for admin.**

1. If you want to have different toolbars for your non-admin, you need to specify it like you did:

```
description = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor', blank=True)
```

and update `CKEDITOR_CONFIGS`  in `settings.py`.

2. If you want to use same setting for all, you just need to do like this:

```
description = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

But you have to have `default` in your `settings`.

**Update after seeing op's answer** op's answer pointed me to another problem in your op's code that I missed before.

Earlier, I did not notice that op is using js to insert ckeditor into `message`. This is not an intended use of `django-ckeditor`.

In your model, you have

```
description = RichTextField(blank=True)
# not need to put "config_name" beause it is set to "default"
```

What you should do is in your template, use `{{ form}}` instead.

Make sure you have `form`in your `contact` view.

```
<form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

{{form.media}}
{{form}}

</form>
```

Remove the following:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'message');
    CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
    CKEDITOR.config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by used this method already. You need to have default

Comment: in my code I used `awesome_ckeditor` as a config name, I mean I already used a config named `default` and it didn't work either.

Comment: Did you copy my code? Since your original code has some other problem besides default. And do you get error message in console?

Comment: Hi, I know you found a solution, but I believe the solution is not ideal. Your answer pointed me to the fact that you are using javascript to insert ckeditor into the template. This is not the way to do, and that was naother reason why default setting did not work. I updated my answer, I hope you an give it another try.